# Powershell Script to parse selected information from txt file and output to csv

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

checked the FAQ's on parsing data and have tried a couple ideas but nothing is working the way I need it. I need a suggestion on how to build a PS script that will read the following information in my .txt file and output only selected information to .csv

```
eamoptns.ftr.0009: LoyaltyPrint3 = "     included with your TV purchase"
eamoptns.ftr.0010: LoyaltyPrint3 = "     included with your TV purchase"

Grand Total: 2 match(es) found.
```

CSV file will contain three columns:

```
Store    Install     Date
```

Need PS script to grab the store # (0009) and add it under the Store column.  If that line contains "included with your TV purchase" under the install column add True if not add False and then add the date in date column.

Code try from comment

```
$PSRoot = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
Get-ChildItem $PSRoot -Filter "*Results.txt" | 
  Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory" } | ForEach-Object { 
    If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern "included with your TV purchase") { 
      New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Club = $A
        Install = $B 
        Date = $C
      } | Export-CSV -Path $PSRoot\Test.csv -Append 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Could you share the code that you have been trying to make work? Or, is this a request for someone to write it for you? Questions without code usually go to https://superuser.com/

Comment: There are many ways this can be done, take a look at Regex for example, this question sure feels like there was zero research investment.

Comment: I concur with the others please provide some of what you've tried so far and then we can assist.

Comment: Here is sample code I was previously using:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested

- choose a regular expression that matches your requrements (see [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6ZvDj4/1))
- iterate the matches and compare the ,matched text
- generate a `[PSCustomObject]` for your csv

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\17\SO_52857274.ps1
$RE = [RegEx]'^.*?\.(\d{4}):[^"]+"\s*(included with your TV purchase|.*)"$'

$CSV = Select-String '.\my.txt' -Pattern $RE | ForEach-Object {
    IF ($_.Matches.Groups[2].Value -eq 'included with your TV purchase'){
        $Install = $True
    } else {
        $Install = $False
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Store   = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
        Install = $Install
        Date    = (Get-Date).Date
    }
}
$CSV
# $CSV | Export-CSV '.\my.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\10\17\SO_52857274.ps1

Store Install Date
----- ------- ----
0009     True 2018-10-17 00:00:00
0010     True 2018-10-17 00:00:00
0010    False 2018-10-17 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you will give it a try

Comment: This works as designed but I'm not able to get it to fail?   In the my.txt file I removed 'included with your TV purchase'  on one of the lines and script didn't log anything.

Comment: ATM the RegEx expects the `.9999:` pattern and any text in double quotes to match the line at all, you should show some more sample lines to match or not in your question. Also your code should be included in the question not in comments.